# Admin page Django not showing models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have created superuser and added model to admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from learning_logs.models import Topic

admin.site.register(Topic)
```

but I cannot see models in admin panel page.

Cannot figure out why!

If I, on purpose, type some syntax error inside admin.py I do not receive any kind of error message.

And this is `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'learning_logs', # MY APP
]
```

Comment: Is your app in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Updated the post with my INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Where is this `admin.py` located?

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: For some magic now it shows the model. Maybe browser cache?

Comment: Prefer using Ctrl + F5 in the future.